# Dropdown increase the size of table row

Tags: html, css, reactjs

Css:-

```
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
   
}

.dropdown_btn {
    font-size: 17px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer; 
   
}


.dropdown_content {
    display: block;    
    background-color: #fff7f7;
    color: #070707;
    cursor: pointer;
    overflow:inherit;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgb(0 0 0 / 20%);
   
}
```

Code:-

```
 <div className="dropdown">
                                            <div className="dropdown_btn"
                                               
                                                onClick={(e) => activeMenu === playdata.idx ? setActiveMenu(null) : setActiveMenu(playdata.idx)} >{playdata.ChannelName}</div>
                                            {
                                                activeMenu === playdata.idx && (
                                                    Channelname.map((val, id) => {
                                                        {
                                                            return (
        <div className="dropdown_content" key={index}>                                                                      
                                                                                {val}

                                                                            </div>
                                                                        )
                                                               
                                                            )
                                                        }
                                                    })
                                                )
                                            }

                                        </div>
```

[image]

[image]

when i click the dropdown the dropdown content increases the size of div which is the table row data i want when i click the dropdown dropdown-content don't increase the table row div
is that possible that when we use the select tag the option taag is not increase the size of table row div

```
.dropdown_content {       
    position: absolute;       
    color: #070707;
    cursor: pointer;
    overflow:inherit;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgb(0 0 0 / 20%);   
}
```

[image]

Comment: You must pop-out your dropdown options with `display: absolute`

Comment: And it must be `className=` and not `assName=` - Lol :D

Comment: update the css .dropdown_content  and also attach the image options is not in correct way

Comment: So style it to look _correct way_. If first time working with absolute elements, google how to work with it

Comment: And you should wrap options to one container to pop it out, not each option separately